# Select box is cleaning after doing get issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a select box where is showing all my ejecutives and when i select an ejecutive it shows policies by ejectuve selected.

My problem is after selecting an ejecutive and getting my results , my select box is starting with the first ejecutive and not the ejecutive selected, seems to be cleaned the selection i did

My tables

```
 TABLE EJECUTIVES
       |id|  |name| |lastname1|
 TABLE POLICIES
       |id|  |num_police|  |ejecutive_id|
```

My models

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
   unloadable
   belongs_to :ejecutive
   has_many :policy

   def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ["ejecutive_id = ? ", search.to_i  ] )
    else
      find(:all)
    end
   end
end

class Ejecutive < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policies
end
```

Here is my controller

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial
      @ejecutives = Ejecutive.find(:all)
      @policies = Policy.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end
end
```

Here is my view

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action =>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= select_tag "search", options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

 Results
     <% @policies.each do |policy| %>
     <p> <%= policy.num_policy%> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.name %> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.last_name %> </p>
     <% end %>
     <%= will_paginate @policies %>
```

Does somebody know about this problem? I'd really appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the selected value in `select_tag` like below

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_for_select( @ejecutives.collect 
                   {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]},
                   params[:search].to_i ) %>
```

Comment: Can you help me with this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936429/error-trying-to-download-using-filnename-format

Comment: check it out...I feel like I know your app like back of my hand :)